# MariaDB How to set a custom/alias datatype on the CAST feature

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sqldatatypes

I'm working with NodeJS / mysql2 / MariaDB  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.7-MariaDB, JSON is not really supported if I understand correctly.
JSON is an alias to a longBlob, with a JSON_VALID  test every  insert or update..

I don't like to parse manually all of my JSON objects on all query results.

I found that it's possible to inject a typeCast function in the mysql connection.

```
  typeCast: function (field, next) {
    if ( field.length === "LONG_BLOB" ) {
      try {
         return JSON.parse( field.string() )
      } catch (err){
         return field.string();
      }
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  }
```

This method is working fine on some case, but not every time

```
  SELECT JSON_OBJECT('a', 1) ... will give a short blob
  {
     type: 'BLOB',
     length: 12582912,
     db: '',
     table: '',
     name: 'sctCap',
     string: [Function: string],
     buffer: [Function: buffer],
     geometry: [Function: geometry]
   }
```

I there a way to force the datatype to LONG_BLOB or to CAST the field to a custom datatype ?

Thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution, may be stupid ... I don't know.
As LONGBLOB casting is not possible, create a function to get it :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` FUNCTION `_ToLongBlob`(
    `a` LONGBLOB
)
RETURNS longtext CHARSET utf8
```

Convert back to JSON :

```
JSON_EXTRACT(_ToLongBlob( JSON_OBJECT("id" , B.id, "nom", B.nom) ), "$") AS
```

Add a typeCast function to the mysql connection :

```
  typeCast: function (field, next) {
    if (field.type === "LONG_BLOB") {
      try {
        return JSON.parse( field.string())
      } catch (err) {
        return field.string();
      }
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  }
```

Comment appreciated if there is a simple way.
Thanks in advance.